# GPA scores program

Tags: c

I am supposed to write a program where  the user is asked how many students there are in a class. Then, it asks for the GPA of each of those students. In the end, it is supposed to display number of students with each GPA score. So far this is what i have, but it doesn't seem to count properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
int cnt1, cnt2, cnt3, cnt4, student, numofsdts, GPA, GPAFreq[4];

printf("Enter number of students: ");
scanf("%d", &numofsdts);

student = 1;

while(student <= numofsdts){
    printf("GPA of student number %d: ", student);
    scanf("%d", &GPA);

    if(GPA < 1 || GPA > 4){
        printf("invalid number \n");
    }
    else{
        student++;
    }

    if(student == numofsdts + 1)
        break;


    if(GPAFreq[1])
        cnt1++;
    else if(GPAFreq[2])
        cnt2++;
    else if(GPAFreq[3])
        cnt3++;
    else if(GPAFreq[4])
        cnt4++;

}

printf("GPA 1: %d students \n", cnt1);
printf("GPA 2: %d students \n", cnt2);
printf("GPA 3: %d students \n", cnt3);
printf("GPA 4: %d students \n", cnt4);
}
```

Comment: First - define what is expected.  Second - describe what is happening.  Then, step through your code with a debugger to ascertain where things are not working. Note: `c` arrays start @ zero

Answer (score 3):

Set `int cnt1 = 0, cnt2 = 0` etc. (they are not nullified by default, just have some garbage [like a rented room not cleaned explicitly...]).

Also:

```
if(GPA < 1 || GPA > 4){
    printf("invalid number \n");
    continue; // skip the rest of the loop body
}
```

Or a slightly cleaner approach (in full):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
int cnt1 = 0, cnt2 = 0, cnt3 = 0, cnt4 = 0;
int numofsdts, GPA;

printf("Enter number of students: ");
scanf("%d", &numofsdts);

students = 0;
while(students <= numofsdts){
    printf("GPA of student number %d: ", students + 1);
    scanf("%d", &GPA);

    if(GPA < 1 || GPA > 4){
        printf("invalid number \n");
        continue;
    }

    if(GPA == 1)
        cnt1++;
    else if(GPA == 2)
        cnt2++;
    else if(GPA == 3)
        cnt3++;
    else if(GPA == 4)
        cnt4++;

    students++;
}

printf("GPA 1: %d students \n", cnt1);
printf("GPA 2: %d students \n", cnt2);
printf("GPA 3: %d students \n", cnt3);
printf("GPA 4: %d students \n", cnt4);
}
```

Comment: You've missed the largest error of all - arrays in `c` are zero based.

Comment: Good point! But actually there is a larger error: GPAFreq is not needed at all! (Or it can be used *instead* of `cnt1`, etc.)

Comment: But you don't know the parameters of the assignment, it may be the first lesson of arrays in his/her class.

Comment: Ok, instead of completing the assignment let's leave the replacing of `cnt1` etc. with `GPAFreq[0]` etc. as an exercise for the reader then (a hint: `int GPAFreq[4] = {}` nullifies all the elements).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors here. The first is that `cnt1-4` have to be initialized prior to being added to. The second is that C uses zero indexing, so `GPAFreq[4]` is not accessing the fourth element of your array (which would be `GPAFreq[3]`.

The third is that your `if` statement isn't doing what you think it is. It is evaluating the values inside of your array as boolean variables, i.e. 0 is `false`, anything else is `true`. A better approach is to do this:
`GPAFreq[GPA - 1] += 1;`
This will be counting the frequencies in each of the indices of the array. Then to print them, you just access `GPAFreq` and no longer need the `cnt` variables.

Comment: initially i did it without using arrays, and it worked fine. However, i need to use arrays but i just don't know how to use them correctly.